# Responsive repeatable background image for body, change in media query to cover

Tags: css, media-queries

I a using the gridless CSS framework for my page.

Body element is used as a wrapper, and I have a background image for that wrapper, which repeats downwards.

Now the problem is, to make this image responsive. Here is the css

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    background-color:#5FB7C0;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width:960px;
    width:90%;
    color:#fff;
    background: url('../img/background.jpeg') repeat-y; 
}
```

The background jpeg is 960 pixel wide.  I thought of making a media query, which makes the background image as a cover when scaling down. I change also the same image but double height, so the background is not scaled up on height.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) { 
body {
    background: url('../img/mobilebg.jpeg');    
    background-size:cover;
}
}
```

But now when I scale down, the background image is not scaled down to smaller sizes if the height is more than the width.

The problem is, the cover property looks that the height is equal to the image, but I need it to look that the width is equal. Also a background size cover which repeats y.

How can I make the image correctly as a repeatable? It can be fixed, but should always look like the picture, but without the spaces left and right if smaller size

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't think you can make image re-size like a fluid layout... at least none of my knowledge..........

Comment: thanks, I know this is difficult, but I basically need the above background as responsive, so that the space on left and right is not shown in smaller screens. Can there be a other way around?

Comment: @Akki619 Wrong. See my post.

Comment: @owl could you please try Barm solution, if it works then great!

Comment: @BramVanroy Could you please set up fiddle for this. This could help everybody.

Comment: Thanks all who helped, Bram had the perfect solution!

Comment: @Akki619 See the edit to my post.

Comment: @BramVanroy Thanks for the fiddle Bram. Upvote for you, gr8 work....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I used 959 px, because 1100px wouldn't make sense If the image is 960px)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { 
body {   
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XdNvj/) that presents sort of what this does.

Answer (score 0):

If your design is fluid, you can target lower resolution like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
body {
    background: url('../img/mobilebg_320pixel.jpeg');    
    background-size:cover;
}
}
```

width needs to be managed a/c to business need.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code To fix your problem. Once I also stuck with the same problem and this code help me and I hope it will help you too.This will work surely.

```
 @media only screen and(max-width:600px){
       body{
            background-image: url(satyam01.jpg);
           background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
        }
    }
```